# Enforce inlining of functions in CoffeeScript or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, inline, v8

I'm trying to structure my code in many short functions, so it is easily readable even without many comments, due to the flow of functions and variable. Last year I we were implementing a high performance application in C which was structured the same way, but the avoid function calls, we annotated virtually every function as inline.

Now I'm writing a NodeJS application in CoffeeScript and have structured a part of my code in tens of small functions which are called from loops. This would aggregate to few hundred - few thousand function calls - depending on the size of the data-structure. Since those functions could be merged into one bigger one, the calls could be avoided, however it would very much degrade the quality of the code.

I've found on SO a reference to [Extreme JavaScript Performance](http://www.slideshare.net/madrobby/extreme-javascript-performance), which is a presentation from 2009 and shows a huge performance improvement when inlining functions on firefox and IE, as well as a noticeable improvement for Chrome and Safari. Now this was 5 years ago and JS-engines are improving with the time, so my question is:

Is it possible to enforce inlining of functions when CoffeeScript creates JS or in JS by the parser, with some specific keyword or parameter?

Or should I simply wait for the V8 engine to realise and handle this automatically (or maybe it is done already)?

Comment: Learn how to use esprima and escodegen, and perform the inlining after the javascript has been created.

Comment: I had a look at both tools, but I'm not sure, they can do what I want. Maybe there is a tool implemented on top of those two, or I just didn't look in the right place.